# VB.Net - Recursion or Iteration

Tags: vb.net, recursion, iteration

first post here because I've got a problem thats got me stumped. I am creating a calculation tool for a project at uni, now I'm not in an it degree but for this project I havent had problem too difficult until now.

Basically I am doing design work for a building, where each floor of the building can be allocated one of 9 possible designs. By then allocating solutions to each of these then calculating costs I am trying to find the most efficient combination.

Normally I would just use some nested loops to find the best design, no problems, but for the calculation tool I am required to change the number of floors, and therefore the number of nested loops, which I am unfamiliar with how to do.

The General structure is this

1- X Number of Floors.

9 Possible designs for each floor.

Based on each combination a cost must be calculated, and if it is within the best 5 results it will be stored.

There is a total of 9^x total solutions.

So

```
Floor = 1
For Solution = 1 to 9

  Floor = 2
  For Solution = 1 to 9

      CalculateCost()
      if CalculateCost < Best Then
      Write, Floor1 Solution Value, Floor2 Solution Value to Output
```

Etc...

Now I am using Vb.net, and do not really know how to do recursion. If someone could simply point me in the way of a resource that may help me on this issue I would be very grateful.

Edit - Whilst I have tried to simplify, the cost of design implementation changes based on various other factors, so I can't simply just take the cheapest design for all. I have tried to solve this through practical theory and so far found so solution, therefore the brute force method is required

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx A for loop.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'd understand it, every design has it's price, isn't then `9*cheapest design-price` the cheapest "combination"? Can you show simplified sample classes?

Comment: Maybe more precision about your (specific) problem with recursion ? VB.Net or something else the principle holds : calling the same method from within it with a different set of parameter all going toward some base case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using `For` loops to try each solution for each given floor, but you're manually iterating through your `Floor` variable. It seems you have 9 independently declared variables with the schema `FloorX Solution Value`. Given all of these things, I think what you really need is a [dynamic array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716275(v=vs.60).aspx). Here's some rough code using this approach:

```
Dim FloorSolutionValues() As Byte ' I'm assuming values of 1-9
Dim NumberOfFloors As Integer ' Get this from the user
ReDim FloorSolutionValues(NumberOfFloors - 1)
For CurrentFloor As Integer = 0 To NumberOfFloors - 1
    For CurrentSolution As Byte = 1 To 9
        If CalculateCost() < FloorSolutionValues(CurrentFloor) Then
            FloorSolutionValues(CurrentFloor) = CurrentSolution
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I'm making some assumptions that may or may not be true, but this should get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks, that did set me on the right path, combined with some of the theoretical limits of the problem this lead me to a solution.